# Nuxt: How to create links in a loop using the data as the link reference

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am reading a set of links from a data source (using $content) and would like to generate a list of HTML elements that will link to the respective page.

```yaml
// test.yaml in content directory
links:
  - id: a
    title: A
  - id: b
    title: B
  - id: p
    title: P
```

Now, I would like to loop through this data and generate a set of HTML links

```html
<!-- page.vue in pages directory -->
 <template>
   <div v-for="link in this._links" :key="link.id">
      <NuxtLink to="/whatToPutHere">{{link.title}}</NuxtLink>
   </div>
 </template>
```

```js
// script
 <script>
   export default {
      async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
         const _links = await $content("test").fetch();
         return _links;
      }
   };
 </script>
```

For each of the items I would like a link such as:

- For id a, the link should be `/content/a`
- For id b, the link should be `/content/b`

Assume that the slug for the above links exist and the pages work as intended. Thanks

Comment: I have used `<a v-bind:href="``/content/${link.id}```">{{link.title}}</a>` and it seems to work. Just wondering if there is a NuxtLink way to achieve the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```js
<NuxtLink :to="`/content/${link.id}`">{{link.title}}</NuxtLink>
```

and it should work

In vue, you don't need to add the whole `v-bind:tag` and can just use `:tag`.
also if you v-bind any tag, whatever is in between quotations will be javascript code.